# Org agenda "wrong number of arguments" error

Tags: windows, emacs, org-mode

I recently went Win7->Win10 on my work PC and org-agenda is now kicking an error.

- GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2018-05-30
- org 9.2.1

I've reduced my org-mode related .emacs down to the following and the issue is persisting.

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-agenda-files (quote ("~/org/inWork.org")))
)
```

When I run org-agenda 'a', I get an empty agenda, dates only, nothing is captured from inWork.org.  The minibuffer displays `Wrong number of arguments: (0 . 0), 2`

Running the same in debug mode gives a backtrace of

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (0 . 0) 2)
org-get-tags(nil nil)
org-agenda-get-deadlines()
org-agenda-get-day-entries("~/org/inWork.org" (2 7 2019) :deadline :scheduled :timestamp :sexp)
apply(org-agenda-get-day-entries "~/org/inWork.org" (2 7 2019) (:deadline :scheduled :timestamp :sexp))
org-agenda-list(nil)
funcall-interactively(org-agenda-list nil)
call-interactively(org-agenda-list)
org-agenda(nil)
funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
call-interactively(org-agenda nil nil)
command-execute(org-agenda)
```

org-agenda 't' fails similarly.  I tried stripping down the org files and .emacs as much as possible, but I haven't been able to isolate the issue.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just uninstalled org 9.2.1, falling back to org 9.1.9 (built-in), and that fixed it.  Agenda scrapes the files, no errors.

Not sure what the problem with 9.2.1. is.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce this  with org 9.2.1 here (although I'm running emacs 27.0.50, but I doubt that that makes a difference). It probably was (and maybe still is) a problem with your configuration which you might want to debug and fix. Reach out to the org-mode mailing list if you need help.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  Will probably just make do with 9.1.9 for now since I already have that working.

Comment: Here's the commit that fixes the bug: https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/c07bf18b502db00ecb2cfc69a54a35c52a78d197

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I upgraded org. When I downgraded I could start the agenda again.

Difference between versions (Non-working/working):

> Org mode version 9.2.1 (9.2.1-33-g029cf6-elpa @ /home/sdaa/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20190225/)
>
> Org mode version 9.2.1 (9.2.1-23-g126a37-elpa @ /home/sdaa/.emacs.d/elpa/org-9.2.2/)

The error-message with 9.2.1-33 is this:
*org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command: Wrong number of arguments*

The emacs-config is the same between org-mode-versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a new install of spacemacs in mac osx. Recompiling elpa fixed it:

```
M-: (byte-recompile-directory package-user-dir nil 'force)
```